# Is it possible to integrate a C++ Solver like IPOPT in an Android App using Android NDK?

Tags: java, android, c++, optimization, android-ndk

I am working on a Android App which will be used as an assistance system for electric vehicles.

For the optimization purposes I have to solve a nonlinear optimization problem with nonlinear constraints. I want to integrate a powerfull Open Source Solver like IPOPT to do that.

I tried to install the solver on my Galaxy Note 4 following these instructions

http://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node14.html

and using IPOPTs Java Interface

http://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node16.html

without succes.

Is there a way to integrate IPOPT using Android NDK or rather a cross compiling  approach?

Or is there an alternative approach to do this?

I would be thankful for any help which brings me closer to my goal.

Comment: It's probably possible unless there's a critical header that's not available on Android. You will have to get it to build using the NDK toolchain, producing a compatible .so or .a file.

Comment: Thanks SteveM. I'm trying to do it. Think there will occure more concrete questions during my first use of Android NDK.

Comment: Part of the difficulty is IPOPT's reliance on a lot of Fortran code, particularly for the compiling of BLAS and Lapack. In any case, I solved this problem, as mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The most difficult part here is due to the fact that IPOPT uses a lot of Fortran code, particularly in its dependencies, like BLAS and Lapack. In fact, you will will very rarely find anybody even trying to compile those for Android, due to the difficulty. Nonetheless, I did it, and recently released exactly what you are looking for.

Here is a simple Android project which uses IPOPT: https://github.com/jeti/android_ipopt_example

It was uses the IPOPT libraries available through this repo: 
https://github.com/jeti/android_ipopt

which were, in turn, created using the standalone Android toolchains with Fortran available through this repo:
https://github.com/jeti/android_fortran

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use this solver:

http://www.joptimizer.com

The building of IPOPT using the NDK toolchain has caused too much effort. Maybe it will be an opinion for another project.